# Did The Creator intend at first for Adam and Eve to have children?

Tags: genesis, creation, adam-and-eve, fall-of-man, will-of-god

We know that Adam and Eve had Cain and Abel and their 600 (I forgot the exact number) after Heaven was taken from them for consuming the fruit. But if hypothetically, if they hadn't sinned, would they give birth to new humans in Eden?

God says **before** "the fall" that He blessed man to be "fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth".

However from what I understand Adam and Eve didn't know what nakedness is, they seem to be so innocent that they wouldn't even know how to "multiply" before eating the fruit, and indeed they didn't had babies in Eden. It seems to me that initially God didn't want billions of humans, just two.

Some even propose the theory that the fruit is a metaphor, a symbol for the sexual pleasure of Adam and Eve. I know some modern literature (not in English, not religious related) that uses the wording "girls that didn't yet tasted the sweetness of the fruit of sin" to describe a virgin woman.

Maybe before the fall, God designed mammals with a non-sexual multiplication, similar to the idea that God designed all creatures to eat plants, but after the fall he permitted meat-eating in humans and animals.

Comment: I don't see anything in the text that indicates that Adam & Eve didn't know what to do - moral innocence isn't the same as mental childhood. Nor is there anything that indicates God only wanted two humans. And even if they didn't know what to do, they could have just asked God!

Comment: This is all opinion-based. 'I forget the exact number' '600' (?) 'they seem to be' 'some ... propose' 'maybe before the fall'. There is no reference and no substantiation to a novel theory.

Answer (score 2):

God told Adam and Eve to "be fruitful and multiply." That's what he wanted them to do.

Adam and Eve being 'so innocent' had nothing to do with them being unable to follow through on what God told them to do.

"It seems to me that initially God didn't want billions of humans, just two." Of course he wanted more: he asked for more.

"Maybe before the fall, God designed mammals with a non-sexual multiplication..." There is no reason he would do that, and no indication that he did.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.